# Why are d3 geo projections necessary?

Tags: d3.js

according to this block https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4090848
it doesn't seem like you need geo projections in order to render a map, but on other blocks such as zoomable ones, they do include a projection. 
Why is it necessary on some d3 maps but not on others?

Comment: That map uses data that is *already* projected - the coordinates in the topojson represent pixel coordinates, not latitude/longitudes. The topojson was created using a d3-projection, likely with a process similar to the one outlined [here](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c). You'll need a projection anytime you are dealing with geographic coordinates (lat/long pairs), while you can use a geotransform, a null projection, or an identity projection for Cartesian data (already projected data).